# implementation of traveling salesman not looping as intended

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences and I want to sort them so that each new sentence only introduces one new word at a time. I think I'm getting close, but the bug that I'm seeing is that each time, the count of new words only increases.
For instance, the first time it loops, sentences with one new word are added to the list. In the next loop, sentences with two new words are added to the list, etc. However, that's not what I want.
Rather, I want each new loop to add sentences with one new word, not to have already incremented to two new words.
I've been debugging for hours, refactoring and rerunning, and haven't caught anything.
Any help?

```
commonSentenceList = list()
alreadySeenWordList = list()
sentenceAndNewWordCountDict = {}

import operator as op

def internalComp(sortedDic, sentenceList, wordList):
    toDelete = list()
    newOutputDict = {}
    secondaryOutputDict = {}
    #this loop is the part that is not working -> each new call should re order and find a new 1 and a new 0, not increase the number every time
    for x in sortedDic:
        sentenceString = x[0]
        if sentenceString not in sentenceList:
            tempCounter = 0
            for word in sentenceString.split():
                if word not in wordList:
                    tempCounter += 1

            newOutputDict[sentenceString] = tempCounter #this dictionary stores sentence and number of new words compared to known word list

    counter = 0
    for key, value in newOutputDict.items():
        if value is 0:
            #here should first check to make sure not dup sentence
            #print(key)
            #print(value)
            toDelete.append(key)
            sentenceList.append(key)
            counter +=1
            for x in key.split():
                if x not in wordList:
                    wordList.append(x)
    if counter is 0:
        for key, value in newOutputDict.items():
            if value is 1:
                toDelete.append(key)
                sentenceList.append(key)
                counter +=1
                for x in key.split():
                    if x not in wordList:
                        wordList.append(x)


    for x in toDelete:
        newOutputDict.pop(x)

    return sorted(newOutputDict.items(), key=op.itemgetter(1))


def travelingSalesman(ListOfSortedSentenceAndScore, sentencesOnlyList, wordList, outputDict):

    #sentencesOnlyList is preloaded with one sentence
    #wordList is preloaded with each word in the sentencesOnlyList
    while any(ListOfSortedSentenceAndScore):
        #return: each element includes sentence and number of new words
        ListOfSortedSentenceAndScore = internalComp(ListOfSortedSentenceAndScore, sentencesOnlyList, wordList) 

sorted_sentenceDataRelativeScoreDict = [('यह बहुत है।', 0), ('यह एक महानदी है।', 6.738544474393532e-05), ('यह मुमकिन है।', 6.738544474393532e-05), ('यह तस्करों का अड्डा है।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मिशन कामयाब रहा', 0.00097574127), ('ज़ोकर बहुत बौना था', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक टेढ़ा विचार था', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह निराली हरकत थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('पर्यटक टूर पर था।', 0.000269897574127), ('पहिया ढीला था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('प्रदर्शनी हाउसफुल थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('वह फुरसत में खेलेंगे।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मेट्रो भूमिगत है।', 0.000227), ('कढ़ी में बहुत मसाला था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मीनार बहुत ऊँची थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक रेतीला तुफान था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक कोरा चेक है', 0.000636119), ('इस उत्पाद में एक खराबी है', 0.0004043126684636119), ('यह एक खोटा सिक्का है', 0.0004043126684636119), ('चरवाहा बहुत चालाक था', 0.0004043126684636119), ('छत पर एक कौआ था', 0.000684636119), ('झाड़ी में एक झींगुर था', 0.000404312668463)]

travelingSalesman(sorted_sentenceDataRelativeScoreDict, commonSentenceList, alreadySeenWordList, sentenceAndNewWordCountDict)

print(commonSentenceList)
```

It seems to me that, within internalComp, the first loop will recreate the newOutputDict based on each previous iteration of sentences. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Rather, it seems that the tempCounter doesn't reset and instead holds the count of number of new words that was from the first instance of the loop.

Comment: sorted_sentenceDataRelativeScoreDict is not defined. I tried {} but travelingSalesman fails to meet the while loop's condition and returns immediately. [mcve]

Comment: My first concern is that when you loop over the dataset, you need to guarantee that it makes some progress towards the end condition. while (not any(somelist)) internalComp(somelist), therefore "internalComp" has to eliminate one thing before it returns.

Comment: my understanding is that `newOutputDict.pop(x)` does that. right? in my testing, the loop finishes without issue. the issue is that `newOutputDict[sentenceString] = tempCounter` doesn't reset to zero for each instance in the loop

Comment: toDelete is empty, so no. It looks like you forgot to put word in WordList, so it never sees a duplicate. But even if that were not the case, your sentences could all have different words, and still not meet the "exactly equal to one" fallback.

Comment: regarding word in word list, does this not take care of that:
`for key, value in newOutputDict.items():
        if value is 0:
            toDelete.append(key)
            sentenceList.append(key)
            counter +=1
            for x in key.split():
                if x not in wordList:
                    wordList.append(x)`

Comment: No, it never executes. Run your own code and see what happens with "if value is 0"

Comment: you're right, it never executes for "if value is 0". so it then goes to "if value is 1" , which does execute. that block appends to toDelete and to wordList. right?

Comment: What do you think "value" is, there?

Comment: i'm wondering in particular if you see something off in the section toward the top that begins with `for x in sortedDic:` and ends with `newOutputDict[sentenceString] = tempCounter`

Comment: i think value is the count of words in that sentence that weren't seen before in any of the previous sentences

Comment: I'm also confused how this is a travelingSalesman problem. Are you finding the shortest sentence which uses all the words and ... meets other conditions you haven't coded? Just curious -- it's not really relevant to fixing the infinite loop. Or is it a vocabulary learning thing?

Comment: yes it's similar to the link that you shared in the section below!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is dependent on "internalComp" making progress towards its termination condition.

```
while condition:
    internalComp()
```

To prove to you that it does not make progress on this data set, please add this to your existing "for x in toDelete"

```
if toDelete:
    for x in toDelete:
        newOutputDict.pop(x)
else:
    print ('toDelete was empty')
    raise Exception('internalComp made no progress. infinite loop may result')
```

Or perhaps add this to the travelingSalesman loop:

```
print (len(ListOfSortedSentenceAndScore))
```

While this may have worked in some of your earlier test cases, you got lucky. If you don't guarantee progress, you will eventually find a data set which triggers an infinite loop. The only safe course is to ensure that internalComp always eliminates at least one.

I believe you have an implementation error on wordList, where you check to see if all the words are in an empty list (which they are not) then you build a word list. Instead, when you find a new word, you should immediately add it to the wordList. But fixing bugs will only reduce your chances of finding a dataset that gives you an infinite loops, if you don't ensure that internalComp makes progress.

Comment: Is this something like what you're working on? http://jtauber.com/blog/2004/11/26/programmed_vocabulary_learning_as_a_travelling_salesman_problem/ Looks like they just detect a stuck case and make a random swap to stir things up. Infinite loop may be acceptable as long as you detect it.

Comment: thanks for the link, that looks very similar to what i'm working on. many thanks for the help, also. you're right, it showed internalComp was making no progress. i'm fixing that today, and still working on a better way of organizing my wordList to fix my error.